# CAPTCHA verification is NOT working

Tags: php, captcha

This is the file to generate captcha image:
**captcha.php**

```
<?php
    generateCaptcha();
    exit();

    function generateCaptcha() {

        $captcha = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
        $captcha = substr(str_shuffle($captcha), 0, 6);
        $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;    // This is NOT working!!

        $font_size = 40;
        $img_height = 60;
        $img_width = 170;

        $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
        imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 0, 50, $text_color, 'font/monofont.ttf', $captcha);

        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);

        imagedestroy($image);
    }
?>
```

This is my **index.php** file:

```
<?php
    require_once "includes/functions.php";
    sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="most">
    <?php echo "<img src='captcha.php'>"; ?>
    <input type="text" name="captcha">
    <input type="submit" name="VerifyCaptcha" value="Verify Humanship">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **process.php** file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['captcha'])) {
        if($_SESSION['captcha'] == $_POST['captcha'])
            echo "You're a human!";
        else echo "I doubt you!";
    } else header('Location: ../');
?>
```

---

Line number 9 in the file **captcha.php** is not working. The session variable is not generated. Any fix?

Comment: Is there any way to store the image on the server and return the link of the image where the function is called?
Like, the function will return a link which will be stored in the variable which will then be used to display the captcha image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally been able to solve the issue!
Updated `captcha.php` file:

```
<?php
    sec_session_start();
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    generateCaptcha();
    exit();

    function generateCaptcha() {

        $captcha = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
        $captcha = substr(str_shuffle($captcha), 0, 6);
        $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;

        $font_size = 40;
        $img_height = 60;
        $img_width = 170;

        $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
        imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 0, 50, $text_color, 'font/monofont.ttf', $captcha);

        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);

        imagedestroy($image);
    }

    function sec_session_start() {
        $session_name = 'admin_panel';
        session_name($session_name);

        $secure = false;
        $httponly = true;

        if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
            header("Location: .../error.php?err=Could not initiate safe session");
            exit();
        }

        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
                $cookieParams["path"],
                $cookieParams["domain"],
                $secure,
                $httponly);

        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to call `session_start();` before even thinking of doing anything with the `$_SESSION` array.

This line should be the first line (not exactly, but you get the idea) that is executed, so I'd recommend putting this before the include `require_once` instruction, as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once "includes/functions.php";
    sec_session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="most">
    <?php echo "<img src='captcha.php'>"; ?>
    <input type="text" name="captcha">
    <input type="submit" name="VerifyCaptcha" value="Verify Humanship">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure to do the same thing in `captcha.php`.

I am not entirely sure what `sec_session_start` does, try putting that line before the `require_once` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: **sec_session_start()** function is defined in the **functions.php** file:

Comment: function sec_session_start() {
  $session_name = 'admin_panel';
  session_name($session_name);

  $secure = false;
  $httponly = true;

  if(ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
   header("Location: .../error.php?err=Could not initiate safe session");
   exit();
  }

  $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
  session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
   $cookieParams["path"],
   $cookieParams["domain"],
   $secure,
   $httponly);

  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id(true);
 }

Comment: I see, then in your ```captcha.php``` file, put ```sec_session_start();``` on top of that file.

Comment: Only one of the two is working: either the session is generated or the image is generated.

Comment: On putting **session_start()**, session variable is successfully generated. But in this case, the image is not getting generated.

Comment: On removing the `session_start()`, the image gets generated but the session variable does not!